# Line width limitation in opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to build an android application for display the geographic data(like google map) with opengl ,and it seems that opengl have a limitation of the line width when drawing lines:

```
        gl.glLineWidth(10); //or gl.glLineWidth(20);
        ......
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINES, 0, 2);
```

And this is what I got:

[image]

It seems that this is the max width of a line rendered by opengl.

However when I see the google map, I found that it can render a much width line for a road like this:

[image]

What's is the problem?

BTW, I wonder if it is desirable to use a game engine in my application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OpenGL implementations do have a limitation for line widths. I believe it varies by implementation. There are a few options, but the easiest one is to just draw a rectangle that is as tall as you need and extends from point A to point B. If you need a 50 point line width, for example, you can get the 4 corners of the rectangle by finding the vector from A to B and projecting + and - 25 points along the normal to that vector at the end points.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I have heard that people use rectangle instead of lines, however it is simple for a straight line, it is easy to calculate the vector, for a curve line, it is difficult I think. Also, it is not easy to handle the join and cap of the lines, isn't it?

Comment: @hguser you're right, all those 2d drawing details are not implemented in Opengl, but libraries exists, (cairo, glamor, ...). If you need to draw fine 2d vector graphics, try digging a bit in such library.

Comment: @j-p:In fact，I have tried `libgdx`,but it seems that it does not support draw wide lines. :(

Comment: @hguser try cairo, they have accelerated surfaces (I'm currently testing how accelerated they are) and is portable. It's a major stack in opensource systems

Comment: @hguser yes, but this is only a small android test [main page](http://cairographics.org/) You may have cairo on android via the [Mono framework](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo), or you make your helper libs in c++ with ndk like in anoek test. There is maybe some java binding for cairo already existing, I've never seek for them...

Comment: A pity.  Any 3d graphic library like cairo? `libgdx` is game oriented.

Comment: cairo aims 2d vector graphics

Comment: For a curved line, you can use various joints. [Mitre joints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miter_joint) are one common method. There are also round joints and bevel joints. There's a nice [picture here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0300__SWT-2D-Graphics/LineJoinStyleJOINBEVELJOINMITERJOINROUND.htm) showing all 3. Mitre and bevel should be straightforward to calculate manually.